# Is there an updated version of Boot Camp coming with Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

Possibly with updated drivers for Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Boot Camp 3.0 comes with Snow Leopard. Windows 7 is supported and I have been using Windows 7 enterprse x64 (RTM) with Boot Camp 3.0 for a couple of weeks on a MacBook Pro Unibody 15". Everything works very well. The nVidia drivers seem out of date but they work better from a heat/battery perspective than hacking the latest from NVidia to get hem installed. There is no driver for the ambient light sensor or the Infineon TPM but otherwise it is fine and the install process is very smooth.

One of the nicer additions is an HFS+ driver for Windows. After Boot Camp 3.0 is installed, the Mac OS X partition is automatically mounted as a read-only drive.

Answer (score 3):

Although the current drivers work fine with Windows 7, I would assume if there were some incompatibilities then updated drivers would be released

Answer (score 2):

Boot Camp will add support for reading HFS+ Volumes, so you will be able to access files on your Mac partition from within Windows.

As to updated drivers for Windows 7, I just don't see the necessity.  I'm currently running Windows 7 RC using the latest Boot Camp drivers from my 10.5.6 Leopard DVD, and everything worked perfectly on first boot.  I did update my video drivers from Nvidia before I tried launching a 3D application, but that's par for the course in Windows.

Comment: Reading HFS+ volumes would be fancy!

Comment: My MacBook Pro audio crackles every 30 seconds... hoping that gets fixed.

Comment: @Shawn Miller: I don't have the crackle issue on my 2009 MacBook Pro with boot camp 3 and win7 rtm. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

There has been no official statement from Apple in this regard, and quite a few people I know have gotten it working under the existing bootcamp with the existing drivers. Apple might do a maintenance update with [Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) but they have not advertised new boot camp features. According to [this](http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/enhancements-refinements.html) list of refinements, there has been no changes to bootcamp